# Making an "analogue display" by drawing boxes

Tags: python, performance, beginner

This is a personal (very amateur) project to teach myself how to use if statements, lists/tuples, loops, etc. It takes an input of one letter and using a pygame-based module `drawly` written by one of my university professors, it draws that letter using numbered boxes (essentially pixels) that "turn on and off" based on their inclusion in `box_list`.

```
letter = input("What should we draw? (Your options are letters A-Z and punctuation marks "
               ". and ?) ")

drawly.start(letter, (170, 370), "aliceblue")

box_list = []
if letter in ("A", "a"):
    drawly.set_color("red")
    box_list = [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("B", "b"):
    drawly.set_color("green3")
    box_list = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]

if letter in ("C", "c"):
    drawly.set_color("darkgoldenrod1")
    box_list = [2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 20, 21]

if letter in ("D", "d"):
    drawly.set_color("blue")
    box_list = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]

if letter in ("E", "e"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 13, 16, 19, 20, 21]

if letter in ("F", "f"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 11, 13, 16, 19]

if letter in ("G", "g"):
    box_list = [2, 3, 4, 7, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]

if letter in ("H", "h"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("I", "i"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 19, 20, 21]

if letter in ("J", "j"):
    box_list = [3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 16, 18, 20]

if letter in ("K", "k"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("L", "l"):
    box_list = [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 20, 21]

if letter in ("M", "m"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("N", "n"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("O", "o"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21]

if letter in ("P", "p"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 13, 16, 19]

if letter in ("Q", "q"):
    box_list = [2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21]

if letter in ("R", "r"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("S", "s"):
    box_list = [2, 3, 4, 7, 11, 15, 18, 19, 20]

if letter in ("T", "t"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20]

if letter in ("U", "u"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21]

if letter in ("V", "v"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 20]

if letter in ("W", "w"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("X", "x"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]

if letter in ("Y", "y"):
    box_list = [1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 17, 20]

if letter in ("Z", "z"):
    box_list = [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 11, 13, 16, 19, 20, 21]

if letter == "?":
    box_list = [2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 20]

if letter == ".":
    box_list = [19]

if letter == "-":
    box_list = [4, 5, 6]

for box_number in box_list:
    x_position = box_number % 3
    y_position = box_number // 3
    if box_number % 3 == 0:
        x_position = 3
        y_position -= 1
    x_position -= 1
    rect((x_position * 50) + 10, (y_position * 50) + 10, 50, 50)
drawly.draw()
drawly.done()
```

As you can see, to turn the boxes on and off, I use `if` statements that assign `box_list` its values based on the input. How can I optimize the assignment of these numbers to `box_list` without using a billion `if` statements?

Comment: I think you're missing an import. `drawly.start(letter, (170, 370), "aliceblue") NameError: name 'drawly' is not defined`

Comment: I probably should have included the whole program, I do have the imports (including ```from drawly import rectangle as rect```) in the full thing, and it does work, but ultimately I saw this as a problem of just assigning the necessary boxes to turn on so I left out details about Drawly. Also my first question. I'll include everything next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## mapping

> ... without using a billion if statements?

Use a `dict`:

```
char_to_appearance = {
    "A": ("red", [2, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 15, 16, 18, 19, 21]),
    ...
    "?": (None, [2, 4, 6, 9, 11, 14, 20]),
    ".": (None, [19]),
    "-": (None, [4, 5, 6]),
}
```

I started out naming it `char_to_boxes`, but then I saw
a subset of letters produce color changes.
It's possible you would prefer to handle color separately.

## downcase

Expressions like `... in ("A", "a"):` are nice enough.
But given that we never draw different glyphs for upper vs lower,
we may as well downcase from the get go:
`letter = letter.lower()`, or perhaps
`letter = input(prompt).lower()`

BTW the prompt neglects to mention the `-` dash punctuation mark.

## plural container

```
box_list = []
```

Yes, we know it's a list, we can see that.
Please avoid suffixes such as `_dict` or `_list`.

This is a container.
It describes more than one box.
So pluralize it: `boxes = []`

## use a function

The `for box_number in box_list:` code should
be packaged up as a function which has a
[single responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle).

```
def draw_character(char: str) -> None:
    color, boxes = char_to_appearance[char]
    if color:
        drawly.set_color(color)
    for box in boxes:
        x, y = box % 3 - 1, box // 3
        # I don't understand what motivated this `if` -- please # comment
        if box % 3 == 0:
            x_position = 2
            y_position -= 1
        w = 50  # width (in pixels) of each square box
        rect(w * x + 10, w * y + 10, w, w)
    drawly.draw()
```

I feel it should be caller's responsibility
to call `drawly.done()`.
At some point you might change the signature
so the function accepts both a character
and a screen position at which to draw the character.
Or, IDK, maybe caller should do that, using `drawly.start()`.
I found no `drawly` documentation on
[pypi](https://pypi.org),
but `rect()` appears to use an offset supplied to `start()`.
I feel caller, rather than this routine, should worry about
applying that (+10, +10) offset.

With all that in hand, you'd be ready for `def draw_string` !

Comment: I don't yet know how to use dictionaries or define functions but these are two things I will research, thanks for the direction (and the convention advice)

Comment: Here is a much simpler `dict` example:  `val = {'one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three': 3}; print(val['three'] + val['two'])`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the points in the [other answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/289546/125403), especially regarding the dictonary recommendation.

While a dictionary is a better way to go, I have some comments regarding the multiple `if` statements.  In your code, they are separate `if` statements, which would imply they are unrelated to each other.  However, that is not the case.  Since they are related, you should use `if/elif`.  That better conveys the intent of the code.

```
if letter in ("A", "a"):
    #
elif letter in ("B", "b"):
    #
elif letter in ("C", "c"):
    # etc.
```

Also, when your code is run, every `if` condition is evaluated (about 30 of them), whereas with `if/elif`, only the conditions which are needed are evaluated.  For example, if the user inputs `A`, only one condition is evaluated.

You should also check for invalid input.  If the user mistakenly inputs a number (like `5`) or a word (like `dog`), you want the code to print a message notifying the user that something unexpected was input.  Your code should probably exit before  continuing on to execute the `drawly.draw()` function.